# Showing that $\|f\|_1$ is not equivalent to $\|f\|_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I have the following norms:
$$
\|f\|_1=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\|f(t)\|_2dt
$$
$$
\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\|f(t)\|_2^2dt}
$$

I need to show their non-equivalence, i.e. that there do not exist numbers $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a\ge b>0$ such that $b\|f\|_2\le\|f\|_1\le a\|f\|_2$.

I would like to do the proof by myself (don't show the full proof please). I am almost sure this has to be a proof by contradiction, so I somehow need to write a few inequalities that give something like this:

$$
\begin{array}{rll}
\|f\|_1 & = & \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\|f(t)\|_2dt \\
 & \le & ??? \\
 & \vdots & \\
 & \le & \text{something}\cdot\|f\|_2 \\
\end{array}
$$

and show that this "something" can take a value that would contradict the assumption that an $a$ exists. However, I do not know how to make the journey from $\|f\|_1$ to $\|f\|_2$ using inequalities, primarily due to the presence of the square root. Could you please help me get started? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(x)=1/(x-t_0)$. What can you say about the norms $\Vert f \Vert_1$ and $\Vert f \Vert_2$?

Comment: @NateRiver But neither of the norms exist for that function, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @ClementC Indeed, you are correct. Sorry, forgot the right exponents. mickep answer got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to construct a sequence of functions $f_n$ in the vector space you work in such that $\frac{||f_n||_1}{||f_n||_2} < \frac{1}{n}$. This will show that a constant $b > 0$ such that $b ||f||_2 \leq ||f||_1$ for **all** $f$ does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I think you mis-typed something after "This will show..."? I'm sorry to say it doesn't make sense to me grammatically. What do you mean by $\|f\|\le a\|f\|$ for instance? There you write it as the same norm, so $\|f\|=\|f\|$...

Comment: You are correct, I forgot the subscripts... sorry!

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't make sense. Do you mean "This will show that a constant $a>0$ *exists*..."? Because, if so, I don't understand what you mean by "similarly for the other inequality", because with $\frac{||f_n||_1}{||f_n||_2} > n$ we have shown that in fact one of the inequalities is satisfied, so doing something "similar" for the other inequality will show that the norms are equivalent - the opposite of what is true.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it again. You can find a constant $a$ such that $||f||_1 \leq a ||f||_2$ (think Cauchy-Schwartz inequality) but you can't find a constant $b$ such that $b||f||_2 \leq ||f||_1$.

Comment: Looking at $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{n}}}$, for instance.

Comment: I would suggest thinking geometrically, about piecewise linear functions such as triangles, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Think of
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-t_0}}.
$$
You can show that $f$ belongs to $L^1$ but not $L^2$.

If you for some reason would like a sequence of functions $f_n\in L^1\cap L^2$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\|f_n\|_{L^2}}{\|f_n\|_{L^1}}=+\infty,
$$
then you can cut the example above off, and consider
$$
f_n(t)=\chi_{(t_0+1/n,t_1)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-t_0}}.
$$
Here $\chi_{(t_0+1/n,t_1)}$ denotes the characteristic function of the interval $(t_0+1/n,t_1)$. (If you want, you might consider only large $n$ so that $(t_0+1/n,t_1)$ is not empty, but that is a minor detail.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: To find a counterexample,  think about $1/x$ on $(0,1]$.

HINT TO A HINT: $1/x$ is $f^2$, not $f$.

Comment: The norms are not even defined for these, are they?

Comment: @ClementC. I am assuming that there are obvious misprints: $\|f\|$ instead $|f|$ under the integral.

Comment: Still, not sure I get it. $1/x$ is not integrable on $(0,1]$, and neither is $1/x^2$. I assume the question at least restricts $f$ to be such that th two quantities to compare exist.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke, Clement has a point... you can't integrate $1/x$ from 0 as it leads to taking $\ln(0)$

Comment: @ClementC.   You are right: the hint was too cryptic. See my hint to a hint.